# Return the value of 1 of the 2 variables that change its value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 1 function that receives 2 variables, these 2 variables can change at any time and I am only interested in the variable that changes in order to do more operations from it.

I need a method that distinguishes that one of the 2 variables changed (int and string), and returns the variable that changed to be able to work with it in other operations.

```
 private checkValues(param1: number, param2: string) {

    // Check values in array by Test
    for(let test of this.valuesT){
      if(test === param2 ){
        this.flagT = true;
        // console.log(this.flagT);
      }
    }
    // Check values in array by testNumber
    for(let testN of this.valuesTN){
      if(testN === param1){
        this.flagTN = true;
      }
    }
    
    // First validation every
    if(this.flagT && this.flagTN){
      return param1
    }
    // Return testNumber if exist changes
    if(this.flagT && !this.flagTN){
      this.valuesTN.push(param1)
      return param1
    } 
    // Return test if exist changes
    if(this.flagTN && !this.flagT){
      this.valuesT.push(param2)
      return param2
    }
    
  }
```

I made a method, but it detects when the variables changed according to the storage of their old states, however, if I want to return to a previous state (which is ideal), it will not be possible, because it is already stored in the array.

Initially both variables start with the same value and are stored in the array, therefore at the beginning in both cases it will be true.

Any suggestions for improvement?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this

```
const checker = (initialArgument1, initialArgument2) => {
  let savedArgument1 = initialArgument1
  let savedArgument2 = initialArgument2
  return (newArgument1, newArgument2) => {
    if(newArgument1 !== savedArgument1 && newArgument2 !== savedArgument2) {
      savedArgument1 = newArgument1;
      savedArgument2 = newArgument2;
     //.....
      return savedArgument1;

    }
    if(newArgument1 !== savedArgument1){
      savedArgument1 = newArgument1;
     //.....
      return savedArgument1;
    }
    if(newArgument2 !== savedArgument2){
      savedArgument2 = newArgument2;
      //....
      return savedArgument2;
    }
    return savedArgument1;
  }
}


// make checker
const myChecker = checker(1, 'test');

// call checker
console.log(myChecker(1, 'foo')); // returns foo
console.log(myChecker(4, 'foo')); // returns 4
console.log(myChecker(6, 'foo')); // returns 6
console.log(myChecker(6, 'blah')); // returns blah
console.log(myChecker(6, 'test')); // returns test
console.log(myChecker(7, 'foo')); // returns 7 - always returns first
console.log(myChecker(7, 'test')); // returns test - check last update was valid
console.log(myChecker(7, 'test')); // returns 7 nothing changed
```

Comment: Hi Jazz, thanks for your answer!

For you, what is "ar"?  
Is the value for compare?
Your function return 1 or 2 values?

Comment: The args are the stored old value and the ars are the new variables. This just returns an array [oldState, newState] but you could easily change that to return whatever you want. What do you want it to return?

Comment: Only the value that changed

Comment: Yes, but no detected the change of the second variable

Comment: If both variables change at the same time it will only return the first. How would you like it to act in that scenario

Comment: Yes, I added that condition, but if the second variable change did not return its value

Comment: I added: 
if(ar1 !== arg1 && ar2 !== arg2){
      arg1 = ar1
      arg2 = ar2
return arg1

Comment: Yes good spot... Ive updated the answer so that it returns argument 1 if both are the same or if there are no changes

Comment: Umm, it is correct, your algorithm if it works, I already tried it separately and it worked. But once implemented in my project, the changes that my variables have curiously only print the number, but if the string changes, it doesn't.

Comment: Is your number actually a string by any chance?

Comment: Ah also make sure your not reinitiating the checker each time checker() should only be called once if you are unsure how it is it being called in your framework you could put a console log right at the top and make sure that's just calling once

Comment: YESSS, it works, !!!!!
I could already adapt it in the best way
Thanks Jazz